# Why does my function to pull certain data from the database has never been called

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I begin my journey with Spring and I have tried to do simple logging application but i stumble accross problem that i cant solve. My code complies but when i try to login even when i insert correct data that exists in db it never let me trough. I believe there is problem with function loadUserByUsername as it has never been called because it neither throws an error or log anything. Bellow is code of my program

user.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "userinfo")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userkey")
    private int userKey;
    @Column(name = "emailaddress")
    private String emailAddress;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
    Optional<User> findByEmailAddress(String email);
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetail userDetail;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(UserDetail userDetail) {
        this.userDetail = userDetail;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                        .permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .permitAll());

        http.userDetailsService(userDetail);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

UserDetail.java

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class UserDetail implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    public UserDetail(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmailAddress(username);
        if(user.isEmpty()){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("This email address does not exists");
        }
        User existingUser = user.get();
        log.info("Email Address: {}, Password: {}", existingUser.getEmailAddress(), existingUser.getPassword());
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                username,
                existingUser.getPassword(),
                Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(existingUser.getRole())));
    }
}
```

MainController.java

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
    @GetMapping("/logout")
    public String logout(){
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

core fragment of login.html

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                <div th:if="${param.error}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid Email or Password</div>
                </div>
                <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                    <div class="alert alert-success">You have been logged out.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" role="form" th:action="@{/login}"
                              class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label class="control-label"> Email address</label> <label for="emailAddress"></label>
                                <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email address" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label class="control-label"> Password</label> <label for="password"></label>
                                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I tried to set up logging in multiple parts of the code, even in controller it always returned email:null and password:null so i believe its problem with this function that is not called

Comment: What was logging at `UserDetail` service class? are you able to see Email Address and Password? and also what is the error you are getting? I suggest you to enable debug and trace logs. please check this answer on how to enable logs https://stackoverflow.com/a/77623968/7078743

Comment: @kcsurapaneni logs are completely fine 0 errors, only log that might have something in common with my case is this: Cache miss for REQUEST dispatch to '/login' (previous null). Performing CorsConfiguration lookup
Logging at UserDetail you can see in my post its this line log.info("Email Address: {}, Password: {}", existingUser.getEmailAddress(), existingUser.getPassword()); gives no result because i think the whole method is not used and intellij tells the same thing "no usages"

Comment: What information should i take look at debuging, i recieve error invalid credentials and acessdenied which is what i knew that i gonna get

Comment: can you see which security filter chain is throwing the error? if possible share the error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I suggest incorporating a custom `AuthenticationProvider`, specifically a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, since it retrieves details from the database. Below is an example code snippet:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain orderFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, AuthenticationProvider orderAuthenticationProvider) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .securityMatcher("/order/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .authenticationProvider(orderAuthenticationProvider)
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return httpSecurity.build();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider orderAuthenticationProvider(UserDetailsService orderUserDetailsService) {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider orderDaoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    orderDaoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(orderUserDetailsService);
    return orderDaoAuthenticationProvider;
}
```

This is a custom `DaoAuthenticationProvider` for handling authentication in a Spring Security configuration. The `orderAuthenticationProvider` method creates and configures the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` with the specified `UserDetailsService`.